# Safety net for array_slice

Tags: php, arrays

I read that `array_merge` will return NULL if you try to merge an empty array and any other array. That's not what I hope to do. I am trying to merge an array with a new array that is actually a slice of another array. (`$i` is an integer).

```
$forgotten = array_slice($matches, $i) ;
$leftOvers = array_merge($leftOvers, $forgotten);
```

The question is, what does `array_slice` return when the index is not found? If it can return null, should I do something like this:

```
$forgotten = array_slice($matches, $i) || array();
```

Also, is there any difference between using `array_merge` like this, and pushing `$forgotten` into `leftOvers`?

Comment: 1) `array_merge()` won't return null only because one of the array is empty. (Also see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) 2) If the offset for `array_slice()` is outside of the array then you just get an empty array 3) Difference between `array_merge()` and pushing it into the array is: `$arrOne = [1]; $arrTwo = [2]`; `array_merge()` = `[1, 2]`; pushing = `[1, [2]]` 4) `$forgotten = array_slice($matches, $i) || array();` PHP is not like JS so you would get a boolean out of this.

Comment: In PHP the result of `||` operator is always boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/it/function.array-merge.php) over an empty array and another array it will return an array composed with the elements of the not empty array. If you try to merge two empty arrays it will return an empty array.

```
array_slice($matches, $i)
```

[array_slice](http://php.net/manual/it/function.array-slice.php) returns an array with all the elements of $matches with index greater or equal $i, if there are no such elements it will return an empty array.

Using [array_push](http://php.net/manual/it/function.array-push.php):

```
 array_push($leftOvers, $forgotten)
```

$result will enqueue an array as a value the end of $leftOvers.

Always try to read the php man when you use a new php function, also you could get all these answers just trying to execute the functions in a test.php file.